# Create WSP package in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, visual-web-part, solution-package, visual-studio-2013

How to create WSP Package in Sharepoint 2013 by Visual Studio 2013.

If I see to bin catalog there are two catalog more. The:

- Debug Catalog
- Release Catalog

How to prepere a WSP Package, to wsp file and move to another server ?

And how to deploy at Another server with Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Package a WSP**

Right click your project in the right column. Then click "Publish".

A dialog will open, where you will get to choose where to place the resulting `.wsp` file. After clicking "Publish" your project will be build and then packaged in the selected location.

Make sure to have the Solution configuration set to `Release` when building for production.

**Install the resulting WSP**

1. Copy the `.wsp` to the server
2. Open an elevated SharePoint Management shell
3. Run `Add-SPSolution -literalpath "C:\Linktowsp\wspname.wsp"`
4. Run `Install-SPSolution -identity "wspname.wsp"` (here you might need to add `-gacdeployment` and `-webapplication` (or `-allwebapplications`) parameters depending on the content of your solution)

Comment: And Robert how to change Site URL in Project Propeties, because if I change to production server rhe Error is caming and rold me: Remote SharePoint site connections are not supported.

Comment: That property has no effect on packaging a .wsp (you should not update it to reflect your production, just keep it pointing at you dev)