# custom timer job issue

Tags: custom-timer-job

I created timer job in dev environment. It is simple one that targets list items and sends communication. It works fine in dev. Before moving it to the other farm I changed all hardcoded url's to reflect other farm setup. 
Then created .wsp file:

- right click the project and select Clean
- changed the soulution configuration to Release > any CPU
- deployed to target farm using steps from [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140592/create-wsp-package-in-visual-studio-2013)

When I run the timer it fails with following error:
*The Web application at http://developmentEnvironmentURL/Sites/TestSite/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.*

How to correctly prepare this timer job to be moved to different farm?

Edit: 
When I go to solution properties and trying to change Site URL following error pops up: Property value is not valid: Remote SharePoint site connections are not supported. (even when Server connection is set to Ofline)

Edit 2: 
When I search entire solution for /Sites/TestSite/ or developmentEnvironmentURL/ (part of the error url) it is not found.

Comment: Check the solution properties, there is a field where you can change the destination url. That url is where the solution will be deployed

Comment: I wouldn't hard code URLs at all.  Use the `SPContext` to get the URL of the farm you're in and use that instead.

Comment: SPContext is not defined in timer jobs

Comment: When I go to solution properties and trying to change Site URL following error pops up: Property value is not valid: Remote SharePoint site connections are not supported.

Comment: You may refer to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2012/02/21/dynamically-retrieve-a-collection-url-from-a-timer-job-during-deployment-jayant-kumar-prabhakar/).